# Serial signal too slow for FPGA serdes

Tags: fpga, serial

I have a serial signal coming from a fiber optic transceiver at 200Mbps, but the serdes on the Ecp5 fpga that I want to use only supports signals as slow as 270Mbps. Between clock recovery, serdes, and 8/10b decode, I would like to avoid having to build all of this myself. Is there any way to adapt the signal or convince the serdes to work with the slower signal?

Comment: Ask the fpga vendor. It sounds like you need to choose the right part for the right job. Trying to fudge something normally ends in tears. I speak from years of experience in making wrong choices.

Comment: what if you told it it was 400Mbps and doubled all the bits? But builtin 8/10b will not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Oversample is the usual approach, but you will likely need to implement your own 8b10 logic.

I do this to get a 125Mb/s MADI stream into an input circuit and transceiver set up for SDI, works fine.

Comment: If I use this approach, can the serdes still do clock recovery?

Comment: Generally yes.  From the transceiver's perspective, it will see "10101101" or whatever as "1100110011110011".  So under certain circumstances you might have issues with run length, but I think with 8b/10b the run length is short enough that it should be fine.